# Interacting with a smart contract method via metamask mint transaction in web3js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I am trying to call a mint function on an ethereum smart contract. When the user clicks the mint button, metamask should open up pointing to the mint method with the correct price and number of mints, and then return a transaction.

However, I am confused as to how this transaction is properly translated towards the smart contract. Also, the price of this is coming out as 0E (should be 0.5E), and frankly I have no idea how to interpret the transaction hash I get out the other side.

The contract for this is here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xeaf59acf00435857d4d0e26e2b48948b86a8a8ca#code

The code for this is below:

```
  const onPurchase = async () => {
    const transactionParameters = {
      gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
      gas: '0x2710',
      to: '0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567',
      from: '0x010bc28dE2E080E233cA98Bc2D03B22D5CA8eD41',
      value: '0x9184e72a',
      data: '0xa0712d680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    };
    const txHash = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [transactionParameters],
    });
  }
```

and the ABI for the mint function looks like so:

```
  {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "numberOfTokensMax5",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "mint",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
  },
```

Comment: Please, share more code in order to allow other people to help you. To decode transactions you can use this very useful tool: https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/

Comment: I would suggest using web3.js or ethers.js library instead of trying to construct the transaction by hand. It is much easier to understand.